# Add A File Attachment to A PHP Email Form Send

Tags: php, forms, email-attachments

Currently I have created a form on a PHP form that posts to the send PHP code. All of the textareas/fields ETC work fine. The issue I have is that I have 3 file fields. The aim is to add 3 file attachments to the email. I just cant work out how to do it.

(Attachment areas at the bottom of the form)

```
<form method="post" action="quote_send.php">
                                       <form class="form-light mt-20" role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Title</label><br />
                                <select name="Title">
                                  <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                                  <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                                  <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                                  <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Forename</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="forename" placeholder="Your Forename">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Surname</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" placeholder="Your Surname">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!----CONTACT DETAILS------>
                            <h3>Your Contact Details</h3>
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Email Address</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="visitormail" placeholder="Your Email Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Contact Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" placeholder="Your Contact Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Address Line 1</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address1" placeholder="Address Line 1">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Address Line 2</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address2" placeholder="Address Line 2">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>City</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="City">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Post Code</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pcode" placeholder="Post Code">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <!----SITE DETAILS----->
                                <h3>Site Contact Details</h3>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Title</label><br />
                                <select name="siteTitle">
                                  <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                                  <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                                  <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                                  <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>     
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Site Contact Forename</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="scforename" placeholder="Site Contact Forename">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Site Contact Surname</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="scsurname" placeholder="Site Contact Surname">
                                    </div>
                                </div> 

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Email Address</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="scvisitormail" placeholder="Site Email Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Contact Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="scnumber" placeholder="Site Contact Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Address Line 1</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="scaddress1" placeholder="Site Address Line 1">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Address Line 2</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="scaddress2" placeholder="Site Address Line 2">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>City</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sccity" placeholder="City">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Post Code</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="scpcode" placeholder="Post Code">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <!----SITE DETAILS----->
                                <h3>Site Details</h3>
                                                                <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Number of Domestic Plots</label><br />
                                <select name="numdp">
                                  <option value="0">0</option>
                                  <option value="1">1</option>
                                  <option value="2">2</option>
                                  <option value="3">3</option>
                                  <option value="4">4</option>
                                  <option value="5+">5+</option>
                                </select></div></div>

                                 <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                 <label>Number of Commercial Plots</label><br />
                                <select name="numcp">
                                  <option value="0">0</option>
                                  <option value="1">1</option>
                                  <option value="2">2</option>
                                  <option value="3">3</option>
                                  <option value="4">4</option>
                                  <option value="5+">5+</option>
                                </select>
                                </div></div>

                                 <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                 <label>Is The Site Visit Required?</label><br />
                                <select name="sitevisitr">
                                  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                  <option value="No">No</option>
                                </select>
                                </div></div>

                                 <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                 <label>Is The Site a Brownfield/Regeneration?</label><br />
                                <select name="brownregen">
                                  <option value="Brownfield">Brownfield</option>
                                  <option value="Regeneration">Regeneration</option>
                                </select>
                                </div></div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                 <label>Is The Site Contaminated?</label><br />
                                <select name="contam">
                                  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                  <option value="No">No</option>
                                </select>
                                </div></div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                 <label>Property Type</label><br />
                                <select name="proptype">
                                  <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
                                  <option value="Flat">Flat</option>
                                  <option value="Detached">Detached</option>
                                  <option value="Semi-Detached">Semi-Detached</option>
                                  <option value="Terraced">Terraced</option>
                                </select>
                                </div></div>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                 <label>Rooms In The Property</label><br />
                                <select name="nrooms">
                                  <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                                  <option value="1">1</option>
                                  <option value="2">2</option>
                                  <option value="3">3</option>
                                  <option value="4">4</option>
                                  <option value="5">5</option>
                                  <option value="6">6</option>
                                  <option value="7">7</option>
                                  <option value="8">8</option>
                                  <option value="9">9</option>
                                  <option value="10+">10+</option>
                                </select>
                                </div></div>

                                 <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                 <label>Do You Have A Gas Supplier? *</label><br />
                                <select name="gsupplier">
                                  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                  <option value="No">No</option>
                                </select>
                                </div></div>

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>If Yes. Who Is Your Gas Supplier?</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gsuppliername" placeholder="Gas Supplier">
                                    </div>
                                </div> 

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                 <label>Who Will Be Carrying Out The Excavation?</label><br />
                                <select name="erxcav">
                                  <option value="MDL">MDL</option>
                                  <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
                                </select>
                                </div></div>



                            <br /><p>  * NOTE: If you do not have a gas supplier in place, you will need to obtain one before any works can be carried out. You can find a gas supplier <a href="http://www.which.co.uk/switch/">here</a>.</p>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                 <label>What Service Do You Require?</label><br />
                                <select name="servicer">
                                  <option value="Gas Connection(s)">Gas Connection(s)</option>
                                  <option value="Gas Disconnection(s)">Gas Disconnection(s)</option>
                                  <option value="Meter Fitting / Exchange">Meter Fitting / Exchange</option>
                                  <option value="Directional Drilling">Directional Drilling</option>
                                  <option value="Outlet Pipework">Outlet Pipework</option>
                                </select>
                                </div></div>

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>What Is Your Hourly Load? (KWh)</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hourl" placeholder="Hourly Load (KWh)">
                                    </div>
                                </div> 

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>What Is Your Annual Load? (KWh)</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="annl" placeholder="Annual Load? (KWh)">
                                    </div>
                                </div> <br /><br /><br /><br />

                                <p>  * NOTE: We require specific documents so we can proceed with your quote. These documents can be seen in the upload section below</p>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Scaled Site Location Plan</label>
                                <input name="sslp" type="file">
                                </div></div>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Domestic Property Schedule</label>
                                <input name="dps" type="file">
                                </div></div>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Site Boundary Drawing</label>
                                <input name="sbd" type="file">
                                </div></div>



                                <p>  * NOTE: We require specific documents so we can proceed with your quote. These documents can be seen in the upload section below</p>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Is There Any Other Information You Think Would Help Us?</label><br />
                                        <textarea class="form-control" name="notes" placeholder="Write you message here..." style="height:100px;"></textarea>
                                </div></div>
                                </div>
                            <br / >
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-two">SUBMIT</button>
                        </form>
```

THE PHP send code.-----------------------

```
<?php
$Title = $_POST['Title'];
$forename = $_POST['forename'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$visitormail = $_POST['visitormail'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1'];
$address2 = $_POST['address2'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$pcode = $_POST['pcode'];
$siteTitle = $_POST['siteTitle'];
$scforename = $_POST['scforename'];
$scsurname = $_POST['scsurname'];
$scvisitormail = $_POST['scvisitormail'];
$scnumber = $_POST['scnumber'];
$scaddress1 = $_POST['scaddress1'];
$scaddress2 = $_POST['scaddress2'];
$sccity = $_POST['sccity'];
$scpcode = $_POST['scpcode'];
$numdp = $_POST['numdp'];
$numcp = $_POST['numcp'];
$sitevisitr = $_POST['sitevisitr'];
$brownregen = $_POST['brownregen'];
$contam = $_POST['contam'];
$proptype = $_POST['proptype'];
$nrooms = $_POST['nrooms'];
$gsupplier = $_POST['gsupplier'];
$gsuppliername = $_POST['gsuppliername'];
$erxcav = $_POST['erxcav'];
$servicer = $_POST['servicer'];
$hourl = $_POST['hourl'];
$annl = $_POST['annl'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
$attn = $_POST['attn'];
$sslp = $_POST['sslp'];
$dps = $_POST['dps'];
$sbd = $_FILES['sbd'];


if (eregi('http:', $notes)) {
die ("Do NOT try that! ! ");
}
if(!$visitormail == "" && (!strstr($visitormail,"@") || !strstr($visitormail,".")))
{
echo "<h2>Use Back - Enter valid e-mail</h2>\n";
$badinput = "<h2>Feedback was NOT submitted</h2>\n";
echo $badinput;
die ("Go back! ! ");
}

if(empty($forename) || empty($visitormail) || empty($notes )) {
echo "<h2>You have missed out required fields, please go back to them and fill them in</h2>\n";
die ("Use back! ! ");
}

$todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;

$attn = $attn ;
$subject = "New $servicer Quote Request";

$notes = stripcslashes($notes);

$message = "Section 1 - Customer Details \n 
Customer Title: $Title
Customer Forname: $forename 
Customer Surname: $surname
Customer Email: $visitormail 
Customer Contact Number: $number
Contact Postal Address:\n $address1 \n $address2 \n $city \n $pcode \n

Section 2 - Site Contact Details \n 
Site Contact Title: $siteTitle
Site Contact Forname: $scforename
Site Contact Surname: $scsurname
Site Contact Email Address: $scvisitormail
Site Contact Number: $scnumber
Site Current Postal Address:\n $scaddress1 \n $scaddress2 \n $sccity \n $scpcode \n


Section 3 - Site Work Details \n
Number of Domestic Plots: $numdp
Number of Commercial Plots: $numcp
Site Visit Required: $sitevisitr
Site a Brownfield/Regeneration: $brownregen
Site Contaminated: $contam
Property Type: $proptype
Number of Rooms in The Property: $nrooms
Gas Supplier Organised: $gsupplier
Gas Supplier Name: $gsuppliername
Who Will Be Carrying Out The Excavation: $erxcav
Service Rquired: $servicer
Hourly Load: $hourl
Annual Load: $annl
Extra Information: $notes

Attached Files: $sslp \n $dps \n $sbd

Please reply to this email within 24 hours to maximise our chances of turning enquiries in to sales.
";
$_FILES ="$sbd";
$from = "From: $visitormail\r\n";
mail("ash.manterfield@btinternet.com", $subject, $message, $from, $_FILES);


?>
                      </span>Thank you <?php echo $visitor ?> for contacting us regarding <?php echo $attn ?>.
```

Any help would be appreciated I've tried a few approaches and cant work out how to do it.

Comment: Why don't you just use PHP mailer ? http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: Take a look at a mail-library, for example https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#readme

Comment: Your code uses depracted functions (`eregi`). Your emailaddress validation is useless. You code is vulnerable to header injection. The last parameter to the `mail` function tells me you have not read the documentation. Yeah seriously: use a library like phpmailer / swiftmailer and read the docs of what you are using.